# Qt QLabel fails to resize

Tags: qt, user-interface, qlabel

I implemented QLabel much like Qt's ImageViewer example, except I use QGridLayout for positioning my widgets. I also implemented similar lines for scaling my QLabel using QScrollBar, but QLabel just doesn't scale like it should inside the QScrollArea. I am not sure if it is related to some kind of GridLayout management issue or something else. I have been reading everywhere and trying different things for 3 days now. Below I list the relevant portion of my code.

In my Viewer class constructor:

```
{
imageLabel1 = new QLabel;
imageLabel1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
imageLabel1->setScaledContents(true);

scrollArea1 = new QScrollArea;
scrollArea1->setWidget(imageLabel1);
scrollArea1->setWidgetResizable(true);

....
QGridLayout *centralLayout = new QGridLayout;
centralLayout->addWidget(scrollArea1, 0, 0);
...}
```

and my scaleImage method:

```
void Viewer::scaleImage1(int factor)
{
  Q_ASSERT(imageLabel1->pixmap());
  scaleFactor *= (1 + factor);
  //imageLabel1->resize(scaleFactor* imageLabel1->pixmap()->size());

  imageLabel1->pixmap()->toImage().scaled(scaleFactor* imageLabel1->pixmap()->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
  imageLabel1->adjustSize();

  adjustScrollBar(scrollArea1->horizontalScrollBar(), factor);
  adjustScrollBar(scrollArea1->verticalScrollBar(), factor);

  imageLabel1->update();
  }
```

My scaleImage1 function is a public slot, and it receives signal from a scrollbar that goes between 0 and 2 so that, into the scaleFactor, the imageLabel1 is designed to be capable of being zoomed in up to 3 times its original size. But when I run the code, I don’t observe the imageLabel becoming enlarged inside the QScrollArea, which I saw in the imageViewer demo. The imageLabel1 simply retains the original size as it is loaded and does not respond to the valueChange() of scrollbar.

I'd appreciate your advice/tips very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think is because you set QSizePolicy::Minimum to the imageLabel, try with [MinimumExpanding or other](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) that better fit your needs.

Comment: I tried changing the sizePolicy to MinimumExpanding and a few others, but the situation stays the same.